# CSS: remove all padding from cell with input field

Tags: html, css, padding, input-field, cellpadding

I have a table row with an input field in each cell that is used to filter a column.

How can I remove all padding from the td's in this row so that there is no extra space between the input field borders and the td's containing them ?
Currently the td's containing input field appear much bigger because of this.

Note: This is just needed for one specific row, all other rows will stay standard-formatted.

**My tr looks like this:**

```
// ...
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input3" /></td>
    </tr>
// ...
</tbody>
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly add a class to the :

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="noPadding">
        <td><input type="text" name="input1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input3" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.noPadding td { padding: 0; }
```

If you find you're still getting extra spacing there may be some margins applied to the inputs themselves (depends on your other CSS / browser defaults) if so worth trying:

```
.noPadding td input { margin: 0; }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're seeing is margin created by the form fields by default, try this:

Css to be placed in your style tags in the head:

```
.noMargin { margin: 0; }
```

Hint: you can assign margin a minus value to reign in the space more, in this instance:

```
.noMargin { margin: -2px; }
```

worked for me (using safari, but will vary by browser)

Your html:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="input1" class="noMargin" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input2" class="noMargin" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="input3" class="noMargin" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to remove padding of all the table tds where it has text input boxes

```
$(function () {
    $('.myTable').find(':text').parent('td').css('padding','0');
});
```

as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/WTBsp/1/